# indefinite articles in 'pose a threat' and 'cause harm'

Tags: phrases, indefinite-articles

Can I confirm that you always need the indefinite article in the phrase 'he poses **a** threat to his community'?
Can you ever instead say 'he poses threat to his community'?

Separately, do you always omit articles in the phrase 'cause harm'?
Can you ever say 'he caused **a** great harm to his community'?

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pose+threat%2C+pose+a+threat&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpose%20threat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpose%20a%20threat%3B%2Cc0) indicates that 'pose a threat' is idiomatic and 'pose threat' is almost never used.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caused+a+harm%2C+caused+harm&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaused%20a%20harm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaused%20harm%3B%2Cc0) indicates that 'caused harm' is idiomatic and 'caused  a harm' is almost never used.

Comment: But googling "there is danger in assuming" and "there is a danger in assuming" indicates that both seem equally idiomatic. Such is English.